# Rearrange vector into matrix

Tags: matlab, vector

In Matlab I have the following vector:

```
a = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ];
```

and I would like to build a matrix making a 1-element swift per row. The output matrix should look as this one:

```
A =

 1     2     3
 2     3     4
 3     4     5
 4     5     6
```

Which is the fastest approach? Thak you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple vectorized solution:

```
a = [ 1 2 30 4 15 6 ]
m = 4;
n = 3;  %// If you want the last element of a to be the bottom right 
        %// element of your output then n must equal numel(a)-(m-1)

[r,c] = ndgrid(0:(m-1), 1:n);
a(r+c)

ans =

    1    2   30
    2   30    4
   30    4   15
    4   15    6
```

Comment: Might be a faster approach - `a(bsxfun(@plus,[0:(m-1)]',1:n))`

Answer (score 2):

a quick answer using arrayfun

```
A = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)(a(:,i:i+2))',1:4,'uni',0))';
```

More generally if you want first `k` elements of `a` in `A` then use: (in above code `k = 3`)

```
A = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)(a(:,i:i+k-1))',1:numel(a)-k+1,'uni',0))';
```

As Dan pointed out, this method is good as a one-liner but isn't fast for large matrices

Comment: If speed is an issue - you will probably find that using a simple for loop and this same logic is faster than `arrayfun` and `cell2mat`

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple for loop and circshift

```
A = zeros(4,3);
for i= 0:3
    answer = circshift(a,[0 -i]);
    A(i+1,:) = answer(1:3);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a late answer, you can also cleverly do this with [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html):

```
A = [1 2 30 4 15 6];
A = hankel(A(1:4), A(4:6))

A =

     1     2    30
     2    30     4
    30     4    15
     4    15     6
```